# I have psycopg2 installed in virtual env, but still getting importerror psycopg2

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I followed the following steps: [I am using Windows 8, Python 2.7.6]

1. I created a virtual environment venv and then did pip install on requirements.txt to install all the libraries.
2. I had to explicitly create a file called config.py to set the os.environ variables. Then, I am doing import config in other files.
3. I have installed postgresql and added bin folder to environment path
4. psycopg2 was failing to install from running requirements.txt. So, I downloaded the zip with setup.py from online, and ran the setup.py in the virtial environment. Later when I did "pip install psycopg2" in the virtual env, it said requirement already satisfied.
5. Now I ran venv/Scripts/.py and got the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "remote-alert.py", line 5, in <module>
>     from database import db_session
>   File "d:\Documents\Tutorials\Technologies\inMobi\soynerdito\HobbesAlert\databa
> se.py", line 12, in <module>
>     isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED" )
>   File "d:\Documents\Tutorials\Technologies\inMobi\soynerdito\HobbesAlert\venv\l
> ib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 344, in create_engine
>     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "d:\Documents\Tutorials\Technologies\inMobi\soynerdito\HobbesAlert\venv\l
> ib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 73, in create
>     dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>   File "d:\Documents\Tutorials\Technologies\inMobi\soynerdito\HobbesAlert\venv\l
> ib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 401, in dbapi
>
> import psycopg2
> ImportError: No module named psycopg2
> ```

In the error output, the file psycopg2.py, which is being accessed exists in the given path. Then why I am getting the error?

I checked many solutions given online, like postgresql must be installed with bin folder in PATH. I should use only virtual env python.exe to run my program, I should not run it as a superuser, etc. Nothing worked for me till now.

Please help!

Comment: I downloaded zip from https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows. Then, I ran pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py27#egg=psycopg2. I also tried installing it by running th setup.py using python.exe in my virtual env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, psycopg2 needs to compile on each architecture; and I am sure if you checked the output of `pip install psycopg2` you would have noticed some errors (even though, in the end, it will end up installing it).

It is best to install the pre-compiled windows binary, which you can find [at this website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: Thanks! But before running this do I have to uninstall the existing psycopg2? If yes, how to uninstall? Also, I need to install psycopg2 in the virtual env and not in my system python. How can I run this exe to install psycopg2 only in the virtual env?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to install it on the system-wide Python.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can manually copy it to the virtual env?

Comment: I manually copied the module folder from system Python/Lib/site-packages to the corresponding folder in virtual env, and now everything is working fine! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows and since i had installed `psycopg2` both on the system python and in virtual environment, I found that with `LIB/site-packages` both had a folder named `psycopg2` though within the virtual environment the contents were fewer.

It worked well when I copied the contents of the system `Lib\site-packages\psycopg2` to those of the corresponding file in virtual environment.