# psycopg2 installing 32 bit

Tags: python, psycopg2

Working in a client environment with a 64 bit machine, a 32 bit python 3.6, and no web access to the outside world (so no pip).

Normally, we install the libraries on our own machine, then copy 'site packages' over. All works just fine, but doesn't for psycopg2. The site admin left me a vm about the error ( and went on vacation). He said he had looked it up and apparently, I need to install the 32 bit version of psycopg2 as it needs to build in it's own environment. All we have is 64 bit.  It's similar to [installing 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314044/i-have-psycopg2-installed-in-virtual-env-but-still-getting-importerror-psycopg2) but not quite the same.

No problem deleting psycopg2-64 from my machine, but how do I force pip to install 32 bit version ? I don't see an option. Do I have any other simple choices.

Apologies for not including the original error. I know it makes it hard to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

I wish to withdraw this. The answer was silly and obvious. I created a 32 bit VM and installed python/pscogpg2 and then moved results into site-packages. All worked perfectly. Not quite the best way to solve but it did work.

Thank you